# Change phone bottom touches color with react native

Tags: react-native

How do I change the color of the bottom touches of the phone in react native. Link to an image.
[image]

Comment: @Scratte It isn't in his program. It's Android navigator bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to that directory:

`your_project/android/app/src/main/res/values`.

There will be `styles.xml` file, open it and there will be something like that:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000</item> // Add this line and change the color
</style>
```

Then go to `your_project/android/build.gradle` and change `minSdkVersion` to **21** or higher.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21 // or higher
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
}
```

If you are using Expo, try to add this to `app.json` file:

```
{
  "androidNavigationBar": {
    "visible": true,

    "barStyle": "light-content" or "dark-content",

    "backgroundColor": color_here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but i'm new to react native and i'm currently dealing with expo. is there a way to resolve it without ejecting expo?

Comment: If you are using expo, then you don’t have access to native code

Comment: Are you using react-navigation?

Comment: yes @Leri Gogsadze i'm using react-navigation and react native latest version. i know it will be hard without ejecting but expo is very convenient to use right now for me

Comment: thank you. i'm checking it to see what happen and i'll be back

Comment: @Kcyr Good. Can you mark it as a correct answer, please?

Comment: it's done. But is there a way to dynamically change the color? i know i'm asking too much

Comment: I don’t think that you can

Comment: I wanted too a few months ago but did’n solve